# wiringPiSetup: Must be root (Did you forget sudo ?)

Tags: wiringpi, qt, qtonpi

I have a problem when I click run it shows this error

wiringPiSetup: Must be root (Did you forget sudo ?)

I also try to write this on terminal 
sudo qtcreator 
to open the qtcreator as sudo but also the problem still thesame with thesame error

actually , I'm using raspberry pi 2 with raspbian jessie operating system

can any one here solve it to me please

Comment: What did you **actually** do? Did you follow the follow the instructions on http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/ ? Finally why are you trying to install it - it should already be in Raspbian Jessie?

Comment: Yes I follow this instructions

Comment: Have you looked up root and sudo?  Do you understand what the error message is telling you to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using netbeans use the below steps.

1. Open the properties of your project
2. Select "Run"
3. Select "Manage Platforms..."
4. Select the Remote Java SE platform you created
5. In the "Platform Properties" section, click the field next to "Exec Prefix"
6. Type in "sudo" (without the double quotes)
7. Optionally test again the platform
8. Close the dialogue box

> If you are using eclipse then try the link
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580279/how-do-i-run-my-application-as-superuser-from-eclipse

You should have an idea now on what the issue is. If you are using some other IDE to run your program then you should look to configure like the steps mentioned for the above IDE's

Also check the post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=33881
There was a similar question posted for qtcreator.
Check the git link https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/issues/69

Comment: How did you determine he is using an IDE? Especially given this: "I also try to write this on terminal sudo qtcreator"

Comment: He tells " when I click run i" , that's what made me think he is using an IDE, the very first line

Comment: I'm using qtcreator not netbeans nor eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code before calling wiringPiSetup():

```
   setenv("WIRINGPI_GPIOMEM", "1", 1);
```

Comment: interesting. I've wrapped wiringPi in Perl and somehow I'd never come across this feature. [wiringPi GPIOMEM](http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-update-to-2-29/).